# Alternative to returning a DataTable from a WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf, datatable, powerpivot

I have a reporting application that interfaces to a users system and returns data to be used in reports.  As I have no control over he data and no knowledge of the data structure I have been using C# DataTables to hold the Data.

A requirement has no arisen to expose the data my application returns through PowerPivot via a webservice, now I understand that I need to use a WCF Data Service to achieve this.

My problem is I don't want to return a DataTable object, I would rather convert it to something more manageable and return that.

Can anybody suggest alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Xml Serialization over the data table which is more manageable and  also a good practice.

Comment: I see your point but I don't think that would work as the ultimate destination for this data is MS Power Pivot, it would have no mechanism to de-serializing the XML

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DataTableSurrogate, it is used in the SyncFramework for serializing DataTables.

[MSDN Data Table Surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.datatablesurrogate.aspx)

Comment: I've tried to use the DataTableSurrogate however when I attempt to return it from my WS I get an error "cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor", it appears that DataTableSurrogate only has one constructor which requires a DataTable.

Comment: Yes, it takes a Datatable in the constructor. I find it convenient to use a Datatable and it sounds like it could be useful for you, because you don't know much about the nature of your data and the DataTable is already quite generic. Otherwise you have to implement something very generic yourself.

Comment: But my issue is I need to return this data via a webservice to be consumed by Microsoft Power Pivot so it looks like using DataTableSurrogate is not a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Pivot and how it consumes data.